# Unable to produce horizonzal scroll with css

Tags: html, css

I have HTML structure like this :

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="fixed_column"></div>
   <div class="fixed_column"></div>
   <div class="fixed_column"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
.wrapper{
  width:500px;
  float:left;
  /*overflow-y:scroll;*/
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.fixed_column{
  float: left;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}
```

So I want only two columns to fit inside my `wrapper`. And so without third column being present it fits inside.

Once I add the third column like in the HTML above, the third column doesn't stay in the same row but it drops to the next line and I <strike>end up with vertical scroller instead of horizontal</strike>. added `overflow-x` to my css and I don't get a horizontal scroll-bar but the third column still drops to the next line.

However I tried to increase `wrapper` to `750px` and this time all three columns fit in the same line so I thought nothing is wrong with my css or did I think wrong?

Why would there not be horizontal scroll once my `wrapper` is `500px` and I have three columns inside with `width:250px` on each.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is because your fixed columns `divs` are only 250px so they never break the 505px container they are currently in.

Here try this.

example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="scroll-container">
        <div class="fixed_column">A</div>
        <div class="fixed_column">B</div>
        <div class="fixed_column">C</div>
    </div>
</div>


.wrapper {
    width: 505px;
    position:relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.scroll-container {
    width:1000px;
}
.fixed_column {
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: You want the scroll-container to size according to it's content. Once your content passes 1000px, it's broken.

Comment: You could just scale it accordingly, unless your content is dynamic and in then you could use the inline-block method

Answer (score 2):

Add white-space: nowrap; to the container, use inline-block instead of float, and use overflow-x instead of overflow-y.

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/vXqY2/

```
.wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.fixed_column {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work like that [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/8dYpG/). Not sure why.

Comment: This won't work perfectly in IE7, just to warn you :-p I was going to recommend the same thing, but the caveat being you will still need a fixed width on the parent container so IE7 doesn't try to make the elements drop down. Also, don't forget to set `white-space: normal;` on the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

The floated elements are going to automatically wrap down to the next level if they start going off the right of the parent container. That's how floats work. To keep them on the same line, you have a few options:

- Make the parent container wider (as you did), but you'll need an extra element for the scrollbar
- Switch from `float: left;` to `display: inline-block;` (as @Alex suggested), but you'll need to make concessions for IE7.
- Switch from `float: left;` to `display: table-cell;`. Don't recommend this, I tried it and it turns out it's kind of painful :-p

See all techniques in a **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kAqmN/)**